# How do I match the last character in an arbitrary string using C# Regexes?

Tags: .net, regex

The obvious attempt is:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @".$", "X", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

This doesn't always work though. Consider the string `\r\n\r\n` - the above produces the surprising result of `\r\nXX`. One might expect from reading [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) (under *Multiline*) that `$` should match just at the end of the entire string, but apparently `$` actually means "match at end of string or at the `\n` just before the end of string".

What might be a correct way to match the last character of an arbitrary string?

Comment: Why REGEX?!? WHY!!!! Just split on \r\n and iterate the lines, getting the last character.  Regex is not the solution for everything.

Comment: There's more involved than just matching the last character. Of course if I wanted just the last character then I'd just go input[input.Length - 1]... No splitting of any kind required.

Comment: Why not just program in regex and forget C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.NET supports the `\z` token, which always matches the end of the string:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @".\z", "X", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: I've got a CLR Assembly using .Net regex and this is perfect for what I need it to do. Thanks.